# Azure Logic App: How do I call a stored proc using a connection string from a Vault secret

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

We have a vault, set up with secrets which we can access from our logic app.. (using get Secret)

We would like to call a stored proc using the values from the secrets, SQL Server, Database name.

Does anyone know what the "Custom value" references would look like, something like "secret:{SQL Server}" ?
[call sp with custom values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4W3e.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can [access Key Vault from Logic App with Managed Identity](https://devkimchi.com/2018/10/24/accessing-key-vault-from-logic-apps-with-managed-identity/) with http connector.

1. Go to logic app Identity and enable it.
2. Go to Azure key vault and add the logic app with secret Get permission.
3. In key vault, set the secret value with serveranme,database and procedureaname.
4. Enter the whole specify secret url with Secret Identifier.
5. Use Compose connector to construct a single output such as a JSON object  from the Http response body.

[image]

Secondly, access properties in json content with Parse JSON and send the the servername and databasename to procedure connector.

6. Use `output('compose')['value']` to get the value property in json object.
7. Set servername and databasename in `Execute stored procedure`.

[image]

The output is as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joey, trying now.. :)

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Comment: Hi Joey, I'm close to having it done. I added a KeyVault, set server/DB, un pw. Used App registrations for the Logic App to use the vault. and can get secrets in the Logic App. When I try to run the SP I have Bad Gateway and I'm trying to debug that now. Thanks for setting me on the right track