# How can I use logic apps to update data in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to know if I can create a logic app in azure where a SQL database is consulted, the information found is sent to the user by e-mail and he has the possibility to accept, reject or modify this information. Finally, I would like to overwrite the information if it was modified by the user in the database.

If it can't do this procedure, what do you recommend I should do?

Comment: Yes you can: [there's a Logic Apps template for running a SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618226/azure-logic-app-how-do-i-call-a-stored-proc-using-a-connection-string-from-a-va) directly from a Logic App. Note that Logic Apps don't support long-running procedure (more than ~3 minutes or so), for that you need to use _Automation Accounts_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by following below process:
Firstly, I have created logic app with below trigger:

[image]

Here in Select query, I can call Stored Procedure or the table which is modified:

[image]

Then you will get a mail for approval.

For multiple approvals [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389328/how-to-have-multiple-approval-areas-in-azure-logic-apps/74427032#74427032).
After approval you can modify SQL table using same logic app workflow or you can create an another workflow for that.